# How to create a folder on a Mac with C++?

Tags: c++, macos, directory

How do you have the user input the folder name and have it created in the desktop (for mac)?
This is what I have so far.. (and extra code underneath)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char game_name [100];
        cout << "Game Name: ";
        cin >> game_name;

        const char* homeDir = getenv ("Home");
        char final [256];
        sprintf (final, "%s/Desktop/%s",homeDir, game_name);
        mkdir(final,0775);
```

other code....
....
...
..

```
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are case sensitive, so you need to use `getenv("HOME")` instead of `getenv("Home")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Boost Library (though there will be overhead of setting up boost on your system but its worth for doing many other stuffs in C++): [boost::filesystem::create_directories()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Convenience-functions)

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

// your code....

boost::filesystem::create_directories("/bla/a");
```

Comment: Boost is overkill for `mkdir()` alone.  However, if you have a lot of these sort of system calls, boost will make it a lot easier to port to other operating systems.

Comment: Yes. That is why I wrote its worth if he wants to do other cool stuffs in C++.